# I have to find pidlist and pmtpid with service id in python

Tags: python, django, string, list, python-requests

File contents:

```
serviceid=2251:tsid=6:orignetwid=99:access=clear:pids=3:clearpids=3:scrambledpids=0:packets=2315:bitrate=1745711:bitrate204=1894282:servtype=1:pmtpid=3251:pcrpid=5251:pidlist=3251,5251,6251
```

Code:

```
file = open('t5001.txt','r')

file1 = file.read()

file2 = file1.split(":")

Input = input("Enter The Service ID :- ")

for i in file2:

    if Input in i:

        print(i)

file.close()
```

I have written this code but not getting answer i am doing just silly mistake not getting that one can anyone will help me

Comment: What's your input? What's the output? What's the _expected_ output?

Comment: I have a file of t5001.txt. data like this (serviceid=2251:tsid=6:orignetwid=99:access=clear:pids=3:clearpids=3:scrambledpids=0:packets=2315:bitrate=1745711:bitrate204=1894282:servtype=1:pmtpid=3251:pcrpid=5251:pidlist=3251,5251,6251) and by taking user input of service id it will give pidlist and pmtpid value

Comment: I want to run your code to see what the problem is, but I don't know what you're inputting in `Input = input("Enter The Service ID :- ")`. What are you inputting there? What does the code output? What are you expecting it to output?

Comment: It will take service id as input and output will be pmtpid=3251 and pidlist=3251,5251,6251 like

Comment: @ForceBru  not coming answer it is saying ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)

Comment: @ForceBru i have edited again it is saying ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this: create a dictionary and save all items, so you can easily retrieve it later:

```py
d = {}
for item in file.read().split(':'):
    key, value = item.split('=')
    d[key] = value

print(d)
# output
# {'serviceid': '2251', 'tsid': '6', 'orignetwid': '99', 'access': 'clear', 'pids': '3', 'clearpids': '3', 'scrambledpids': '0', 'packets': '2315', 'bitrate': '1745711', 'bitrate204': '1894282', 'servtype': '1', 'pmtpid': '3251', 'pcrpid': '5251', 'pidlist': '3251,5251,6251'}
```

If you want to get a list `['3251','5251','6251']` instead of pure string `3251,5251,6251`, add one more condition check:

```py
d = {}
for item in file.read().split(':'):
    key, value = item.split('=')
    if ',' in value:
        d[key] = value.split(',')
    else:
        d[key] = value

print(d['pidlist'])
# output
# ['3251','5251','6251']
```

Once you have constructed the dictionary `d`, things are easier:

```py
if Input == d['serviceid']:
    print('pidlist: ', d['pidlist'])
    print('pmtpid: ', d['pmtpid'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use exec function?

```
file = open('t5001.txt','r')

for i in file.read().split(':'):
    try:
        exec(i)
    except NameError:
        pass
#only access = clear won't be executed

file.close() 

Input = int(input("Enter The Service ID :- "))

if serviceid==Input:
    print(f'{pidlist = }\n{pmtpid = }')
```

U have each & every value (except `acccess`) referenced to by a variable with the very name as in the file.

Output:

```
Enter The Service ID :- 2251
pidlist = (3251, 5251, 6251)
pmtpid = 3251
```